# The Disappearance

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

On an unknown date, Robert Hensworth's wife, Ashley, suddenly disappeared without a trace.  Her body was found long after her disappearance. The police are trying their best to investigate, but there is one crucial clue they need: **the date she was abducted.**
Strangely, this is the only thing the police don't have. They know Ashley had a laptop, so they search through it. The murderer has corrupted the drive of the computer, but they are able to recover it via specialized tools.
The only contents are this file:
[image: victim.jpg]
Robert has also told them the things Ashley was obsessed with:
1. **the IUCN Red List**
2. **pandas**
3. **odd numbers**
4. **light**
After months of trying, they have come up with nil. But now, they've employed **you**. Can you, based on Ashley's obsessions and the image, figure out when she was kidnapped?

**NOTE:** The kidnapper made the image, and previously knew Ashley's obsessions.

Comment: Why is the writing on the image so poorly contrasted :(

Comment: I guess it is for hiding it: XSL TDODKS-XMELZGL CY EPS RC TSO SZQY XDB-TSEWLQCN ZCJ HKT

Comment: Yeah, the message was purposely contrasted that way

Comment: @SahibPrime according to the IUCN Red List there are multiple endangered "Pandas", namely the Red Panda and the Giant Panda. Is this part of the riddle or was she generally obsessed with Pandas?

Comment: She was obsessed with pandas in general (probably the giant panda, as it is the most common)

Answer (score 1):

Partial Answer:

There is writing on the file part from the **you won't find her**. It reads:

> XSL TDODKS-XMELZGL CY EPS RC TSO SZQY XDB-TSEWLQCN ZCJ HKT

Comment: You're on the right track! Now you just need to figure out WHAT to do with that writing...